# Equivalence between voltage drop across capacitors and resistors?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

In simulating a circuit, comprised of 2 capacitors of same size but different dielectrics, their capacitance ratio ${C1}/{C2} = \epsilon2/\epsilon1$. 
Problem is, in finite element programs, I am allowed to enter resistivity. Using the simple formulas, the resistance $R1/R2 = \rho1/\rho2 $.

Is it correct to state that to obtain the same field behavior as in dielectrics while using resistance to simulate your system, one should maintain the ratio $\rho1/\rho2 =\epsilon2/\epsilon1 $?

I do not know if my logic is correct. Could anyone shed some light on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a normal practice (for measurement purposes) to balance a resistor pair
against a capacitor pair (in a bridge measurement...).   In that situation,
the expected balance occurs when the capacitance conductance ratio is the
same as the resistive conductance ratio.   So, in the terms of
your example, the balance would compare the ratio ϵ2:ϵ1 with
the ratio ρ1:ρ2.   That is because capacitive conductance is proportional
to the 'ϵ' value, but resistive conductance is inversely proportional
to the 'ρ' value, so the ratios are reversed.
As to the question of a finite element modeling program, the solutions of electric field in space around capacitor plates are boundary value problems in which the
plates are held to be equipotential surfaces, while the solutions of electric field in shaped resistive media are constrained to have nil voltage gradient perpendicular to the resistive material's sidewalls.   I see no general similarity.